# Vue push into nested array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications

I have a vue application where I am trying to save an array which consists of a date field and has another array inside with time and time has startTime and untilTime as values.
What i want to achieve is that that when I click on a button the fields connected to time.startTime and untilTime should be added on button click. But I am getting this error:

```
    vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Avoid using non-primitive value as key, use string/number value instead.

found in

---> <DatePickerComponent> at src/components/DatePickerComponent.vue
       <VCard>
         <VThemeProvider>
           <VDialog>
             <VsRow>
               <VCard>
                 <NextMeetingCardComponent> at src/components/NextMeetingCardComponent.vue
                   <DashboardComponent> at src/views/DashboardComponent.vue
                     <VMain>
                       <VApp>
                         <App> at src/App.vue
                           <Root>
```

I am a bit new to vue and javascript could someone point out my error maybe?

```
 <template>
      <div>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="12">
          <v-menu v-for="item in dates" :key="item"
            ref="menu"
            v-model="menu"
            :close-on-content-click="false"
            :return-value.sync="dates"
            transition="scale-transition"
            offset-y
            min-width="auto"
          >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }" >
              <v-text-field
                v-model="item.date"
                label="Picker in menu"
                prepend-icon="mdi-calendar"
                readonly
                v-bind="attrs"
                v-on="on"
              ></v-text-field>
            </template>
            <v-date-picker
              v-model="dates"
              no-title
              scrollable
            >
              <v-spacer/>
              <v-btn
                text
                color="primary"
                @click="menu = false"
              >
                Cancel
              </v-btn>
              <v-btn
                text
                color="primary"
                @click="$refs.menu.save(dates)"
              >
                OK
              </v-btn>
            </v-date-picker>
          </v-menu>
          <v-btn v-on:click="addTimeFields()">Add Time</v-btn>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
        <v-row v-for="i in dates" :key="i">
          <v-col
            cols="6"
            sm="6"
          >
              <v-text-field
                v-model="i.time.startTime"
                label="Starttime"
                type="time"
              ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col
            cols="6"
            sm="6"
          >
            <v-text-field
              v-model="i.time.untilTime"
              label="Untiltime"
              type="time"
            ></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    
      </div>
    
    </template>
    <script>
   export default {
  name: "DatePickerComponent",
  data: () => ({
    dates: [{date: new Date().toISOString().substr(0,10), time: [{
        startTime: "",
        untilTime: ""
      }]}],
    timeInputFields:[],
    selectedDate: [],
    menu: false,
    modal: false,
    menu2: false,
  }),

  methods:{
      addTimeFields(){

        this.dates[0].time.push({
          startTime: "",
          untilTime: "",
        })


      }
  }



};
</script>
```

Output Vue:

[Vue output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04g6O.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues.

1. time is not an array, it is an object
2. You don't have 2 dates in the array, so probably want the 0 based index.

#2 is where the error is coming from.

```
      addTimeFields(){

        this.dates[0].time.push({
          startTime: "",
          untilTime: "",
        })
      }
```

Since your first entry already has start and until times set, to update you just need to to:

```
  this.dates[0].time = {
    startTime: "",
    untilTime: "",
  }
or

  this.dates[0].time.startTime = "",
  this.dates[0].time.untilTime = "",
```

## EDIT one

I created a code pen for your code, there are quite a few errors, probably around the setup, but this screenshot shows what happens if you add two dates into the array. You get a list of them at the top, and then a list of the times. This makes me think you probably are just wanting one?
[image: screenshot when adding two dates into array]

Please see this pen, https://codepen.io/OblivionSY/pen/rNyOLpw?editors=1011 it is not amazing, and doesn't fully work (date picker has an error)

Some general notes though:

1. make sure your :key value are primitive (string, int etc) and unique
2. try and split up the functionality into components. If you have multiple dates, then have one component to deal with editing a single date and the respective times.

feel free to edit the pen if you want me to take another look.

Comment: I had just changed my code I had changed time to an array inside my array because I have to be able to insert multiple times to one date. But now I am getting a new warning and it prevents me from getting the inputfields.

Comment: I tried to do what you told me, but I am getting the same error as in my code the error is updated in my post above

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your vue output, so can visualise what is going on?

Comment: Hi, just added a screen from the output, what I want is when I click on add time button I want another row of starttime and untilltime to be rendered. So i can save multiple times

Comment: thanks. Another issue you have is you have `v-model="i.time.startTime"` but time is an array, so you probably want to loop through the various times? Can you have multiple dates? or one date and multiple times?

Comment: I can have multiple dates but one date at a time will be saved and one date can have multiple times . For example 05.05.2021 can have 13-14 and 15-16 o clock as start and until time.

Comment: if this is an editor where you pick one date, and then can add multiple times, and the control returns one single date with N times, then we should remove the dates being an array. confirm, and I'll see if I can make a code pen quickly, I need to write something similar so it will actually be mutually helpful

Comment: Hi, thanks for the effort, I will sit down on it again in a few hours just need a break from work today. Maybe I will get something to work too then I will post it here

Comment: Hi, Simon, I fixed the error with the times array, I first save it in another array and push this array to my time array inside dates. with this it works. Thanks for your efforts to, if you are interested in the fix let me know

Comment: yea, if you have a sample code or something to see it would be useful - thanks. If you can mark this is an answer if it did help :)

Comment: I will post my soolution tonight :) and yes you helped me out to find some errors